# how to store my query data into array in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, storing-data

regarding in query from the model, i got already the values and store it from a variable, now i want it to be stored from a data array for further use, how can i do this, i am in controller from codeigniter.

Here is my controller full code:

```
  public function move_data($queue_id) {
        $data = array();
        $user = array('user_id' => $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['user_id']);
        $getqueuedata = $this->Clinic_model->queue_data($queue_id,$user);
        //echo json_encode($getqueuedata);

        $data = array (
        'queue_id' => $getqueuedata['queue_id'],
        'user_id' => $getqueuedata['user_id'],
        'clinic_id' => $getqueuedata['clinic_id'],
        'order_num' => $getqueuedata['order_num'],
        'patient_id' => $getqueuedata['patient_id'],
        );
  }
```

when i `//echo json_encode($getqueuedata);` uncomment this line, and comment the array storing, i will have this:

```
[{"user_id":"102","clinic_id":"2","order_num":"1","patient_id":"7","status":"2","time_sched":null,"queue_id":"1"}]
```

in my full code, i got error, i dont know how to store the values of my query from array.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @FrankerZ i want only to store the values of $getqueuedata that is the result of my query into array, but i am doing wrong. whats the correct?. i got error .

Comment: you can use [row_array()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) in queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

function 'queue_data` return result like this  :

```
//$getqueuedata =  json_decode($json,true);

Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 102 [clinic_id] => 2 [order_num] => 1 [patient_id] => 7 [status] => 2 [time_sched] => [queue_id] => 1 ) )
```

So you can store data as this way:

```
$data = array (
       'queue_id' => $getqueuedata[0]['queue_id'],
       'user_id' => $getqueuedata[0]['user_id'],
       'clinic_id' => $getqueuedata[0]['clinic_id'],
       'order_num' => $getqueuedata[0]['order_num'],
       'patient_id' => $getqueuedata[0]['patient_id'],
       );
print_r($getqueuedata);
```

If your function return array object:

```
$data = array (
       'queue_id' => $getqueuedata[0]->queue_id,
       'user_id' => $getqueuedata[0]->user_id,
       'clinic_id' => $getqueuedata[0]->clinic_id,
       'order_num' => $getqueuedata[0]->order_num,
       'patient_id' => $getqueuedata[0]->patient_id,
       );
```

Comment: thnks for understanding my question.. ii'll try this

Comment: hello sir i got error Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array